# Java: Optimal approach for storing and reading 1 billion data records

Tags: java, performance, serialization, file-io, storage

I'm looking for the fastest approach, in Java, to store ~1 billion records of ~250 bytes each (storage will happen only once) and then being able to read it multiple times in a non-sequential order.

The source records are being generated into simple java value objects and I would like to read them back in the same format.

For now my best guess is to store these objects, using a fast serialization library such as Kryo, in a flat file and then to use Java FileChannel to make direct random access to read the records at specific positions in the file (when storing the data, I will keep in a hashmap (also to be saved on disk) with the position in the file of each record so that I know where to read it).

Also, there is no need to optimize disk space. My key concern is to optimize read performance, while having a reasonable write performance (that, again, will happen only once).
Last precision: while the records are all of the same type (same Java value object), their size (in bytes) is variable (e.g. it contains strings).

Is there any better approach than what I mentioned above? Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated !

Many thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Have you considered putting them in a database? That would get you more sophisticated indexing for low programming cost.

Comment: There is no real need for complex indexing: I just need to know where to read a specific record (its position in the file will never change). My guess is that using a DB will be much slower (significant overhead to communicate with DB, etc.).

Comment: I was thinking of indexing more for performance, especially in selecting what to keep in memory.

Comment: Just for keeping a Map<Integer, Integer> in memory, holding the position of each record, you'll need many gigabytes of memory. Not sure it's doable the way you intend to. Maybe you should find a serialization format that always takes the same size on disk, to have an easy way to map a record number to a file location.

Comment: It would be a Map<Long, Long>: 16 bytes per entry + some overhead. I have 16Gb of RAM => I should be able to run it with only limited disk swap (done by the OS), right? Alternative is to store it in 2 long[] arrays (one for the record id, and another for the position in file): no Map overhead.

Comment: How many elements are you planning to read? Have you got an unique identifier for each element?

Comment: a Map<Long, Long> uses much more than 16 bytes per entry. Even with 16 bytes per entry, multiplied by 1 billion records, you've already exhausted your 16 GB of memory.

Comment: Each record will be read multiple times (for statistical analyses). I have a unique identifier (long) but maybe worthwhile to optimize this into an int (reduce memory footprint)

Comment: @JB: indeed, I'm considering to use 2 long[] arrays (or 1 int[] and 1 long[]) , have them sorted as per record id and then do a binary search when I need to find a position in file

Comment: It seems to me to be more like a case for a B-tree, or some other structure with wider fan-out than binary search, with the higher levels kept in memory. Binary search over a billion entries is going to do about 30 random accesses to a data structure that may not fit in physical memory.

Comment: Any clue as to the distribution of reads over the data?  Uniform?  Bell shaped? Also, some samples of the data entries themselves would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Lucene, it will take care of everything you have mentioned above :)
It is super fast, you can search results more quickly then ever.
Apache Lucene persist objects in files and indexes them. We have used it in couple of apps and it is super fast.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Reading the description "Apache LuceneTM is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform." => it seems relevant for text, while in my case I am storing non-text data + I know exactly which record I would like to read (no sophisticated search needed). Am I missing something? Any hint on where I should look specifically for in Apache Lucene? Thx!

Comment: Just look at the demo provided on the website (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description)
Secondly you can also read the book "Lucene in Action, 2nd Edition"
Moreover you can store your non-text data anywhere but index it (location, index, id) Lucene to fetch it really fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an embedded Derby database. It's written in Java and you can actually run it up embedded within your process so there is no overhead of inter-process or networked communication. It will store the data and allow you to query it/etc handling all the complexity and indexing for you.

Comment: Thanks but embedded Derby (or H2, even faster) takes ~200ms for a simple random query. Early tests with my approach show ~1ms for a simple random query => for now my approach seems to be the fastest